# In KDB, can we use deferred response with .z.ph and .z.pp?

Tags: kdb

I am trying to build a RESTful API service in KDB. Users will be making queries through a webpage. Queries are captured via .z.ph and .z.pp handlers. However, I am struggling with using .z.w to send back response. Any ideas on how we can use deferred response for HTTP queries? Can we use -30!(::) as we would use in .z.pg?

I am getting the following error - 
‘Nothing to defer. Handle 8 was not expecting a response msg
Thank You

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is no, -30! will not work with HTTP requests. There are already some open-source API services you may be able to use like [q-REST](https://github.com/AquaQAnalytics/q-REST), which can be configured to either execute functions predefined on the kdb process, or accept custom queries.

q-REST will receive HTTPS requests through a java app and send them as individual IPC requests to kdb. On your kdb side you can then handle these IPC requests as per any usual IPC handling (async, deferred async etc). q-REST also has built-in basic authentication.